# trigger click inside an iframe - jquery dialog button - only in Safari

Tags: jquery, iframe, safari, jquery-dialog

I have a JQuery dialog which displays an IFrame and a "Send button (which resides outside of the IFrame)

When defining the dialog, I am creating a button which is supposed to trigger a click event in  a button which is inside the IFrame:

```
$(dlg_id).dialog({
buttons:
{ 
  "Send": function() { 
      $(dlg_id).contents().find('#btn_in_iframe').trigger('click'); 
  }
}
```

});

Everything works find in IE, Chrome and FireFox

In Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2) the click event is not triggered

All I need is to call a function inside the IFrame, doesn't need to be a triggered event

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can access the context of an iframe with contentWindow (which did work for me with Safari):
`document.getElementById('IframeId').contentWindow.anotherFunction()`

Of course the iframe source must be on the smae domain/protocol, otherwise that's a different cup of tea.